# Python-like map in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, static-assert

My problem with `std::transform` is that I can't both get the beginning and the end of a temporary object.

I would like to implement a Python-like mapping function in C++ that works on vectors of a type and maps them to another vector (of possibly another type).

This is my approach:

```
template <class T, class U, class UnaryOperator>
std::vector<T> map(const std::vector<T>& vectorToMap, UnaryOperator operation)
{
    std::vector<U> result;
    result.reserve(vectorToMap.size());
    std::transform(vectorToMap.begin(), vectorToMap.end(),
        std::back_inserter(result), [&operation] (U item) { return operation(item); });
    return result;
}
```

And this is an example of how I intend to use this (where the return type of filter is the type of its first argument):

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Cluster>> getClustersWithLength(const std::vector<Cluster>& clusterCollection, const int& length)
{
    return map(filter(clusterCollection, [&length] (Cluster& cluster) {
           return cluster.sizeY == length;
       }),
       [] (const Cluster& cluster) {
        return std::make_shared<Cluster>(cluster);
       });
   }
```

The error message I get for this code though is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'map(std::vector<Cluster>,
ClusterPairFunctions::getClustersWithLength(const
std::vector<Cluster>&, const int&)::<lambda(const Cluster&)>)'

note: candidate: template<class T, class U, class UnaryOperator> std::vector<_RealType> map(const std::vector<_RealType>&, UnaryOperator)
 std::vector<T> map(const std::vector<T>& vectorToMap, UnaryOperator operation)
note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'U'
```

Can you give me some help, how do I fix it? Also, can I somehow use compile-time static assertion to check if the type of operation(T t) is U?

Removing `U` and replacing the declaration of result with `std::vector<typename std::result_of<UnaryFunction(T)>::type> result;` still produces an error:

```
src/ClusterPairFunctions.cc: In function 'std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Cluster> > ClusterPairFunctions::getClustersWithLength(const std::vector<Cluster>&, const int&)':
src/ClusterPairFunctions.cc:130:14: error: could not convert 'map(const std::vector<_RealType>&, UnaryFunction) [with T = Cluster; UnaryFunction = ClusterPairFunctions::getClustersWithLength(const std::vector<Cluster>&, const int&)::<lambda(const Cluster&)>]((<lambda closure object>ClusterPairFunctions::getClustersWithLength(const std::vector<Cluster>&, const int&)::<lambda(const Cluster&)>{}, ClusterPairFunctions::getClustersWithLength(const std::vector<Cluster>&, const int&)::<lambda(const Cluster&)>()))' from 'std::vector<Cluster>' to 'std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Cluster> >'
       return (map(filter(clusterCollection, [&length] (Cluster& cluster) {
In file included from src/../interface/ClusterPairFunctions.h:5:0,
                 from src/ClusterPairFunctions.cc:1:
src/../interface/../../../interface/HelperFunctionsCommon.h: In instantiation of 'std::vector<_RealType> filter(const std::vector<_RealType>&, UnaryPredicate) [with T = Cluster; UnaryPredicate = ClusterPairFunctions::getClustersWithLength(const std::vector<Cluster>&, const int&)::<lambda(Cluster&)>]':
src/ClusterPairFunctions.cc:132:4:   required from here
src/../interface/../../../interface/HelperFunctionsCommon.h:52:15: error: no match for call to '(ClusterPairFunctions::getClustersWithLength(const std::vector<Cluster>&, const int&)::<lambda(Cluster&)>) (const Cluster&)'
   if(predicate(*it)) result.push_back(*it);
               ^
src/ClusterPairFunctions.cc:130:68: note: candidate: ClusterPairFunctions::getClustersWithLength(const std::vector<Cluster>&, const int&)::<lambda(Cluster&)> <near match>
   return (map(filter(clusterCollection, [&length] (Cluster& cluster) {
                                                                    ^
src/ClusterPairFunctions.cc:130:68: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
In file included from src/../interface/ClusterPairFunctions.h:5:0,
                 from src/ClusterPairFunctions.cc:1:
src/../interface/../../../interface/HelperFunctionsCommon.h:52:15: error: binding 'const Cluster' to reference of type 'Cluster&' discards qualifiers
   if(predicate(*it)) result.push_back(*it);
               ^
src/../interface/../../../interface/HelperFunctionsCommon.h: In instantiation of 'std::vector<_RealType> map(const std::vector<_RealType>&, UnaryFunction) [with T = Cluster; UnaryFunction = ClusterPairFunctions::getClustersWithLength(const std::vector<Cluster>&, const int&)::<lambda(const Cluster&)>]':
src/ClusterPairFunctions.cc:135:4:   required from here
src/../interface/../../../interface/HelperFunctionsCommon.h:64:9: error: could not convert 'result' from 'std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Cluster> >' to 'std::vector<Cluster>'
  return result;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your code made a touch more generic:

```
template <template<class...>class Z=std::vector, class C, class UnaryOperator>
auto fmap(C&& c_in, UnaryOperator&& operation)
{
  using dC = std::decay_t<C>;
  using T_in = dC::reference;
  using T_out = std::decay_t< std::result_of_t< UnaryOperator&(T_in) > >;
  using R = Z<T_out>;
  R result;
  result.reserve(vectorToMap.size());
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  std::transform(
    begin(cin), end(cin),
    std::back_inserter(result),
    [&] (auto&& item) { return operation(declype(item)(item)); }
  );
  return result;
}
```

To make the above work in C++11, you'll have to add trailing return type `-> decltype(complex expression)` and replace the nice `std::decay_t<whatever>` with `typename std::decay<whatever>::type` or write your own aliases.

These steps:

```
  using dC = std::decay<C>;
  using T_in = dC::reference;
  using T_out = std::decay_t< std::result_of_t< UnaryOperator&(T_in) > >;
  using R = Z<T_out>;
```

need to be moved to a helper type

```
template<template<class...>class Z, class C, class Op>
struct calculate_return_type {
  using dC = typename std::decay<C>::type;
  using T_in = typename dC::reference;
  using T_out = typename std::decay< typename std::result_of< Op&(T_in) >::type >::type;
  using R = Z<T_out>;
};
```

giving us this:

```
template <template<class...>class Z=std::vector, class C, class UnaryOperator>
auto fmap(C&& c_in, UnaryOperator&& operation)
-> typename calculate_return_type<Z, C, UnaryOperator>::R
{
  using R = typename calculate_return_type<Z, C, UnaryOperator>::R;
  R result;
  result.reserve(c_in.size());
  using T_in = typename calculate_return_type<Z, C, UnaryOperator>::T_in;

  using std::begin; using std::end;
  std::transform(
    begin(c_in), end(c_in),
    std::back_inserter(result),
    [&] (T_in item) { return operation(decltype(item)(item)); }
  );
  return result;
}
```

but really, it is 2016, do attempt to upgrade to C++14.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cba8ce8a206399e)

---

In C++14,  I find curry-style works well

```
template<class Z, class T>
struct rebind_helper;
template<template<class...>class Z, class T_in, class...Ts, class T_out>
struct rebind_helper<Z<T_in,Ts...>, T_out> {
  using type=Z<T_out, Ts...>;
};
template<class Z, class T>
using rebind=typename rebind_helper<Z,T>::type;

template<class Op>
auto fmap( Op&& op ) {
  return [op = std::forward<Op>(op)](auto&& c) {
    using dC = std::decay_t<decltype(c)>;
    using T_in = dC::reference;
    using T_out = std::decay_t< std::result_of_t< UnaryOperator&(T_in) > >;
    using R=rebind< dC, T_out >;
    R result;
    result.reserve(vectorToMap.size());
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    std::transform(
      begin(cin), end(cin),
      std::back_inserter(result),
      [&] (auto&& item) { return operation(declype(item)(item)); }
    );
    return result;
  };
}
```

both of these need a "reserve if possible" function (which does SFINAE to detect if `.reserve` exists, and if so reserves; otherwise, doesn't bother).

The second looks like:

```
auto fmap_to_double = fmap( [](auto in){ return (double)in; } );
```

which can then be passed a container and it remaps its elements to `double`.

```
auto double_vector = fmap_to_double( int_vector );
```

On the other hand, maybe always producing vectors might be a worthwhile simplification.  However, always only consuming vectors seems pointless.

Comment: @AdamHunyadi Verbose C++11 version added.

Comment: @AdamHunyadi Typos and remaining C++14 stuff removed, live example included.

Comment: I'm trying to use this and in some scenarios it works, but sometimes it does not... I think it has something to do with reference binding, but I cant deduce the errors.

Comment: @AdamHunyadi Can you do a stacked crooked or something with a simplified case that doesn't work?  If you are working in MSVC, all bets rae off, because it has very questionable C++11 support...

Comment: here is the minimum example; basically, I want to use it to make shared ptr-s from values.
http://pastebin.com/LRcEn0dE

Comment: @AdamHunyadi Clang states "error: cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'int *' with an lvalue of type 'const int *'".  That seems correct, you cannot create a `shared_ptr<int>` from an `const int*`.  Are you looking to copy the value?  If so, use `std::make_shared<int>(value)` not `std::shared_ptr<int>(&value)`.  [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8dbc72d7bacaf7cb)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having `U` as a template parameter, you can simply declare your result vector like this:

```
std::vector<typename std::result_of<UnaryFunction(T)>::type>
```

Comment: This still produces an error message. I added it as an edit to the question.